# `autoref{}` refers to a figure as an equation

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, captions

I have a figure in my document, but when I use `autoref{}` to refer to the figure, it refers to it as "Equation 2.1". This figure is in section 2.1, so I suppose that's where the number comes from but I don't understand why it takes the section number and why it's labelled as a section?

Here is my figure's code:

```latex
\begin{figure}[ht]\label{fig:density_function}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=6 cm]{gumbel_density_function_graph.png}
    \caption{The density function of a Gumbel distribution}
\end{figure}
```

I've managed to make it work, i.e., to make it reference "Figure 2", by putting the label below the `\caption{}` (it works only at that specific place), but then the hyperlink brings me to the caption and not the figure (I have to scroll up to see the figure each time).

Is there a reason why this happens? (Sorry, I haven't put a complete buildable code, but I'd need to give the picture too)

Comment: The label belongs after the caption.  Use the hypcap package to get the link right

Comment: Thanks! (again!)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer commented, using the `hypcap` package (with the `all` option) solved my problem. I added the following code to the preamble:

```latex
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
```